# lookup field is not getting populated in URL hacking in custom related list button in lightning

Tags: lightning, custom-button, urlhacking, relatedlistnew

lookup field(Master) is not getting populated in URL hacking in custom related list button(Child object) in lightning. It is getting populated in classic.

I have one parent object named Sample Request  and its child object Sample Product having master detail relationship.

I created one custom button with url hacking to set some fields and recordtype id for sample product creation which is  in related list of Parent object(Sample Product).

In classic parent lookup field in getting populated while clicking on related list button but it is not working in lightning. Lokkup field is empty.
I have used this code:

```
/a0m/e?CF00Na000000ATqLW={!Sample_Request__c.Name} 
&CF00Na000000ATqLW_lkid={!Sample_Request__c.Id} 
&RecordType="{!$Label.UsCanSampleProductRecordType}" 
&retURL=%2F{!Sample_Request__c.Id}
```

I need to display this button in related list.
I thought of creating lightning action but it is not getting displayed in related list section as only list buttons can be displayed in related list section.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

URL hacking does not work with Lightning.
The recommended workaround is to use Actions.
https://www.salesforce.com/video/300736/
https://douglascayers.com/2018/08/05/legitimate-url-hacking-in-lightning-experience/